# Playing m3u8 files on jwplayer without rtmp

Tags: html, flash, video-streaming, jwplayer, m3u8

I built this bit of code from a pretty long search on the web full of failures trying with various players to play this,

```
http://85.132.71.4:1935/turktv/ntv.sdp/playlist.m3u8
```

m3u8 stream. I will put up my compact(paste it into an html file) code in here in hopes someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you for reading.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dev.landgraaf.net/jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='livefeed'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('livefeed').setup({
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '480',
    'height': '300',
    'provider': 'video',
    'file': 'http://85.132.71.4:1935/turktv/ntv.sdp/playlist.m3u8',
    'image': 'http://dev.landgraaf.net/webcam.jpg',
    'bufferlength':5,
    'modes': [
        {type: 'flash', src: 'http://dev.landgraaf.net/player.swf'},
        {
          type: 'html5',
          config: {
          levels: [ {'file': 'http://85.132.71.4:1935/turktv/ntv.sdp/playlist.m3u8'} ],
           'provider': 'video',
           'x-webkit-airplay': 'allow'
          }
        }
    ]
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Title and tag say video.js, but your code is jwplayer…

Answer (score 0):

M3U8 does not run in Flash mode in JW5. You would need JW6 for this. Here is some more information - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28856/using-apple-hls-streaming, if you would like a trial of us, please contact us - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/

Comment: sir, can we use this in order to play rtmp files in android, without a flash plugin ? will it work ?

Comment: No, you cannot run RTMP on Android without Flash. That is not possible.

Comment: Hi Ethan, does Jwplayer 6 support m3u8 files with mp4 file urls ? I am unable to play my videos, here is my content from m3u8,---- >#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=200111, RESOLUTION=512x288
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3000444, RESOLUTION=400x300
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=400777, RESOLUTION=400x300
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

Comment: I think they have to be ts? Do you have a link?